# Cannot terminiate a process while running script from a browser

Tags: php, iis

I've been searching for an answer for this one for a few days now and am hoping someone here can help.

I have a PHP script that runs from a browser and is suppose to kill a process by process ID.  I've tried executing a number of commands via exec like this:

```
$output = array();
$return = 0;
exec($cmd, $output, $return);
```

I've used this with the following different values for $cmd:

```
"cmd /c taskkill.exe /F /PID $pid";
"cmd /c taskkill /F /PID $pid";
"taskkill.exe /F /PID $pid";
"taskkill /F /PID $pid";
```

In each case, $output comes back as an empty array and $return gets a value of 1.  The process, however, doesn't terminate.  If I run any of these commands directly from the command line, they work.  Is this an issue running the script from the browser?

I'm running PHP 5.4.31 on IIS6 (windows 2003)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: shell_exec returns all of the output stream as a string. exec returns the last line of the output. Maybe there is more information to see. You can also use system. I used shell_exec before, but had the same trouble passing a variable http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your feedback.  I've tried using system() and passthru() as well, with no luck.  In both of those cases, the function returned an empty string, with a return integer value of 1.  Again, the actual process isn't terminating.  The only other thing I can think of is that its the actual command, or its running it through the web browser.  Any other ideas or advice would be welcome.  Thanks!